# How to define a simple Address attribute in TypeDB?

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I'm just getting started with TypeDB and have a basic question about the schema concepts:

How would I model that a *Person* has an *Address*? I.e. a composite attribute like an address that is composed of 3 values:

1. city,
2. street,
3. ZIP code?

My understanding is that an attribute can have exactly ONE value definition, but it can own any number of other attributes.

My attempts:

```
street sub attribute, value string;
city   sub attribute, value string;
zip    sub attribute, value long;
```

## (1) Attribute without value?

```
address sub attribute,
    // value ... (does not make sense here) ???
    owns street,
    owns city,
    owns zip;

person sub entity,
    owns address;
```

## (2) Modeled as relation?

```
address sub relation,
    relates street,
    relates city,
    relates zip,
    relates subject; // ???

person sub entity,
    plays address:subject;
```

## (3) As entity?

```
address sub entity,
    owns street,
    owns city,
    owns zip;

person sub entity,
    owns address; // ??? is owning another entity possible?
```

Which one (if any) would be the recommended way to go?

Comment: I'd lean towards address being an entity, since it's a unique, tangible, identifiable thing. And a person having an address is a relation. 
e.g.:
`lives-at sub relation, relates person, relates address;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An address works best as an entity because, as @2bigpigs said, an address is an entity as it has a [distinct existence in the domain](https://docs.vaticle.com/docs/schema/concepts#entity). Other examples of an entity include an organisation, a location or a person. You can see that an address fits right in among those.